# Proper De-duping syntax in My

Tags: mysql, navicat

I'm rolling up on `CustomerID`, and I'm getting duplicates in my output. What is the proper de-duping syntax to use here for MySQL?

```
SELECT a.*, c.CBS, c.Region
FROM account a
JOIN customer c on (a.CustomerID = c.CustomerId)
WHERE (a.ProductID LIKE '%m3%' OR a.ProductID LIKE '%m4%') 
      AND a.OpenDate < '2015-10-17' AND a.Term = '360' AND c.CBS >= '690' 
      AND c.Region != 'National';
```

Comment: What do you mean by *rolling up*? I see just an `INNER JOIN`. What is the relationship between the two tables?

Comment: for avoid duplicated you should use distinct  ...  but with a select a.*  i have doubt that you are really proper duplicated  rows

Comment: #1 and 2. They both have the same primary: CustomerID. Meaning, I'm pulling different data from two tables regarding the same entity.